# Django send_mail method : Include session userid in mail message

Tags: django, django-views, sendmail

I was able to use send_mail method and it works without any problem.
What I am trying to achieve is to include session's username in mail message.

My views.py allow a certain authenticated user to create numbers. On successful addition of numbers, an email is triggered to the administrators, which at the moment does not include user's userid. So the administrators have no way of knowing which user created the numbers.

My attempt to get userid displayed in mail body below. I also tried another variant  -

```
            #send mail
            subject= 'Numbers created by {request.user}'
            message = 'This user {request.user} has created numbers. '
            from_email= settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
            to_list = [settings.EMAIL_ADMIN]
```

Comment: if you are trying to use it f string arent you missing `f` while initialization string?

Comment: Thanks Mohit, I did miss f string format and plus, I was incorrectly using request.user method.

username = request.user
subject= f" Numbers created by {username}"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @MohitC, I did miss f string format and plus, I was incorrectly using ```request.user method. username = request.user 
subject= f" Numbers created by {username}"